# QNetworkAccessManager uploadProgress and QProgressBar

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QT program that uploads a set of files via Http POST using the QNetworkAccessManager. Everything uploads just fine, but I'm having trouble connecting the uploadProgress with a progressbar.

This is the code that does the uploading:

```cpp
QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
while (numNetConn > 3) {
    qDebug("Waiting for the number of transfers to decrease. [%d]", numNetConn);
    QTest::qWait(500);
}
QNetworkReply* reply = networkManager->post(request, multiPart);
multiPart->setParent(reply); // delete the multiPart with the reply
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onGetReply()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)), SLOT(progressChanged(qint64, qint64)));

void MainWindow::progressChanged(qint64 a, qint64 b) {
    if (b > 0) {
        qDebug() << "Uploading " << a  << "/" << b << "%" << (double)a/(double)b*100.0;
        ui->progUpload->setValue((a/b)*100);
        qApp->processEvents();
    }
}
```

The debug window happily shows lots of progress while uploading, but the UI does not update until the very end of the upload when it jumps to 100%.

```
...
Uploading  171606016 / 172918683 % 99.2409
Uploading  171835392 / 172918683 % 99.3735
Uploading  172064768 / 172918683 % 99.5062
Uploading  172294144 / 172918683 % 99.6388
Uploading  172523520 / 172918683 % 99.7715
Uploading  172769280 / 172918683 % 99.9136
Uploading  172918683 / 172918683 % 100
```

What am I missing from the progressChanged() function to update the UI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your percentage calculation is:

```
(a/b)*100
```

`a` and `b` are both integer types here, so until `a` equals `b`, `a/b` evaluates to `0`.

To get the behavior you want, you can do the multiplication first:

```
100*a/b
```

You could also cast the integers to `float` or `double` (as you do in your `qDebug` statement).

Comment: You are correct! I can't believe I did that... Because I correctly displayed it to the debug output. `ui->progUpload->setValue(((double)a/(double)b)*100.0);` also works. Thanks!